# Error: Cannot find module 'config': Javascript, module is in the same folder directory

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to import database module in my main express script. However I get the

```
Cannot find module 'config'
```

error. I don't understand why, because they are in the same folder and the path I import from is correct.

[image]

**app.js**:

```js
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const cors = require('cors')
const morgan = require('morgan')


const db = require('config')

const app = express()
app.use(morgan('combined'))
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(cors())

app.get('/test', (req, res) => {
  res.json({message: "Testing..."})
})

app.post('/register', async (req, res) =>  {

    console.log("register before db")

    await db.query("INSERT INTO users (username, password, email, created_date) VALUES  ($1, $2, $3);",
        ['test2', '222', 'test2@', '2020-01-02']);

    res.send({
        message: "Registered! Email: " + req.body.email +
            ", password: " + req.body.password
    })
})

app.post("/login", (req, res) => {

})

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8081)
```

**config.js**:

```
var pg = require('pg');

const pool = new pg.Pool({
    user: 'myname',
    password: '123456',
    host: 'localhost',
    'port': '5432',
    database: 'mydatabase'
})

pool.on('connect', () =>     {
    console.log('Connected!');
});

module.exports = {
    query: (text, params) => pool.query(text, params),
};

console.log("Done!")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you just write it `config` then it will search on `node_modules` or nodejs api. you should specifically write it `./config` then it will work.

`./` indicates local module on *this* folder. and use `../` to load module from parent directory.

Comment: Thank you! It worked! Will accept your answer